# How to make .configure(text="lorem ipsum") only display in a given amount of time (e.g. only shows for 5 seconds)?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Right now, for instance if I click the "copy" button for Username, the "*Username copied!*" will display there forever. I only want it to display for 5 seconds and the "*Welcome*" in the `description = Label(window, text="Welcome")` will show again.

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
from urllib import parse
from tkinter import Tk

window = Tk()
window.title("CopyText")
window.geometry('295x150+600+210')

large_font = ('Verdana',11)
small_font = ('Verdana',10)

#USERNAME ===================

lbl = Label(window, text="Username:")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
entry1Var = StringVar(value='myusername')

txt = Entry(window,textvariable=entry1Var,font=large_font, width=18)
txt.grid(column=1, row=0)

def clicked():
    copy = txt.get()
    r = Tk()
    r.withdraw()
    r.clipboard_clear()
    r.clipboard_append(copy)
    description.configure(text="Username copied!")
    r.update()

btn = Button(window, text="copy", command=clicked, height=2, width=5)
btn.grid(column=2, row=0)

#PASSWORD ===================

pword = Label(window, text="Password:")
pword.grid(column=0, row=4)

entry2Var = StringVar(value='mypassword')
pwordtxt = Entry(window,textvariable=entry2Var,font=large_font, width=18)
pwordtxt.grid(column=1, row=4)

def clicked():
    copy = pwordtxt.get()

    r = Tk()
    r.withdraw()
    r.clipboard_clear()
    r.clipboard_append(copy)
    description.configure(text="Password copied!")
    r.update()

btn = Button(window, text="copy", command=clicked, height=2, width=5)
btn.grid(column=2, row=4)

#EMAIL ===================

email = Label(window, text="Email:")
email.grid(column=0, row=6)

entry3Var = StringVar(value='myemail@gmail.com')
emailtxt = Entry(window,textvariable=entry3Var,font=large_font, width=18)
emailtxt.grid(column=1, row=6)

def clicked():

    copy = emailtxt.get()


    r = Tk()
    r.withdraw()
    r.clipboard_clear()
    r.clipboard_append(copy)
    description.configure(text= "Email copied!")
    r.update()

btn = Button(window, text="copy", command=clicked, height=2, width=5)

btn.grid(column=2, row=6)

description = Label(window, text="Welcome")
description.grid(column=1, row=7)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: *""It looks like your post is mostly code"*: [Edit] and strip down your code for **one** example `entry`. One solution I can think of, use `.after(1000)` count the loops, after 5 loops set `text='Welcome'` and exit `.after(...`.

Comment: Note: I'm not a moderator, not even a trusted user, I just happen to have the edit privilege: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges